# Keras autoencoder with pretrained embeddings returning incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I have been attempting to replicate a sentence autoencoder loosely based off of [an example from the Deep Learning with Keras book](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/Chapter07/sent-thoughts-rnn.py).

I recoded the example to use an embedding layer instead of the sentence generator and to use `fit` vs. `fit_generator`.

My code is as follows:

```
df_train_text = df['string']

max_length = 80
embedding_dim = 300
latent_dim = 512
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 10

# prepare tokenizer
t = Tokenizer(filters='')
t.fit_on_texts(df_train_text)
word_index = t.word_index
vocab_size = len(t.word_index) + 1

# integer encode the documents
encoded_train_text = t.texts_to_matrix(df_train_text)

padded_train_text = pad_sequences(encoded_train_text, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

padding_train_text = np.asarray(padded_train_text, dtype='int32')

embeddings_index = {}
f = open('/Users/embedding_file.txt')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))
#Found 51328 word vectors.

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_dim))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector


embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            embedding_dim,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=max_length,
                            trainable=False)
inputs = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="input")
embedding_layer = embedding_layer(inputs)
encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(latent_dim), name="encoder_lstm", merge_mode="sum")(embedding_layer)
decoder = RepeatVector(max_length)(encoder)
decoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(embedding_dim, name='decoder_lstm', return_sequences=True), merge_mode="sum")(decoder)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoder)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")


autoencoder.fit(padded_train_text, padded_train_text,
                epochs=num_epochs, 
                batch_size=batch_size,
                callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I verified that my layer shapes are the same as those in the example, however when I try to fit my autoencoder, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected bidirectional_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (36320, 80)
```

A few other things I tried included switching `texts_to_matrix` to `texts_to_sequence` and wrapping/not wrapping my padded strings

I also came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731059/keras-lstm-autoencoder-with-embedding-layer) which seems to indicate that I am going about this the wrong way. Is it possible to fit an autoencoder with the embedding layer as I have coded it? If not, can someone help explain the fundamental difference between what is going on with the provided example and my version?

EDIT: I removed the `return_sequences=True` argument in the last layer and got the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected bidirectional_1 to have shape (300,) but got array with shape (80,)`

After updating my layer shapes are:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (InputLayer)           (None, 80)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_8 (Embedding)      (None, 80, 300)           2440200   
_________________________________________________________________
encoder_lstm (Bidirectional) (None, 512)               3330048   
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_8 (RepeatVecto (None, 80, 512)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_8 (Bidirection (None, 300)               1951200   
=================================================================
Total params: 7,721,448
Trainable params: 5,281,248
Non-trainable params: 2,440,200
_________________________________________________________________
```

Am I missing a step between the `RepeatVector` layer and the last layer of the model so that I can return a shape of (None, 80, 300) rather than the (None, 300) shape it is currently generating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Embedding` layer takes as input a sequence of integers (i.e. word indices) with a shape of `(num_words,)` and gives the corresponding embeddings as output with a shape of `(num_words, embd_dim)`. So after fitting the `Tokenizer` instance on the given texts, you need to use its `texts_to_sequences()` method to transform each text to a sequence of integers:

```
encoded_train_text = t.texts_to_sequences(df_train_text)
```

Further, since after padding `encoded_train_text` it would have a shape of `(num_samples, max_length)`, the output shape of the network must also have the same shape (i.e. since we are creating an autoencoder) and therefore you need to remove the `return_sequences=True` argument of last layer. Otherwise, it would give us a 3D tensor as output which does not make sense.

As a side note, the following line is redundant as `padded_train_text` is already a numpy array (and by the way you have not used `padding_train_text` at all):

```
padding_train_text = np.asarray(padded_train_text, dtype='int32')
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my code. It's very much appreciated. Pretty new to Keras and still getting a hang of the layer shapes. After I removed the `return_sequences=True` arg in the last layer I got a new error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected bidirectional_1 to have shape (300,) but got array with shape (80,). Not sure if it's any help, but I added a bit more info in at the bottom of my question along with the layer shapes of the updated model.

Comment: @scribbles Since you are building an autoencoder the input and output of the model are the same. Therefore, if you give it an input of shape `(80,)`, the output must have a shape of `(80,)` too. To fix this, just change the number of units in the last layer from `embedding_dim` to `max_length`. By the way, I don't think you would get good results since you are trying to build an autoencoder based on word indices and they are not in a limited range, so it would be very unlikely for the model to give the indices values as output and have a good performance. >>>

Comment: @scribbles >>> That's the main difference with the autoencoder based on embedding values which may give much better result. However, don't rely on this saying of me and try it for yourself and see if you could get good results or not.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! One more question if it's not too much to ask - is it possible to return the original embedding layer shape `(80, 300)` vs. the input layer shape of `(80,)`? The book example pre-embeds the word vectors having an input shape of `(80, 300)` and then outputs `(80, 300)` from the last bidirectional lstm layer. My goal was to calculate the reconstruction error between the input/output layers (using cosine distance or similar). I was hoping to role the embedding step into the modeling process itself but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @scribbles Yes, you are doing it correctly if that was your goal. You want to embedding lookup (i.e. going from word indices to corresponding word embeddings) to be explicitly in the model. Of course, you can output the embeddings and have an output shape of `(80, 300)`. However, for that you need to pass the corresponding embeddings of each input sample when calling `fit()` method (i.e. replace its second argument with the corresponding embeddings for the first argument).

Comment: thanks. Can you elaborate a little more on “you need to pass the corresponding embeddedings of each input sample when calling fit”? Im not sure I understand what that means. Sorry if I’m being a bit dense.

Comment: @scribbles Let me put it this way: the second argument of `fit()` method is the expected output of model which you need to specify. Now, if you would like to have the word indices as output, then your current code is fine (expect for the change for the output shape). Otherwise, if you want to have the word embeddings as output then you must give it the true word embeddings as output when training (i.e. calling `fit()`). Is it clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183306/discussion-between-scribbles-and-today).